# Some property of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, radicals

We have that $I$ is an ideal in ring $R$.
How prove: if $x^a \in I$ and $y^b \in I$ show that $(x+y)^{(a+b)} \in I$?
I don't have any idea. I know what is it ideal

Comment: Do you know binomial expansion?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how it can be helpful for prove it @beingmathematician

Comment: Just input and see some of the terms of binomial expansion. And aware of that R is a ring so we have $x^a \cdot y^b$ in R

Comment: Is the ring commutative?

Comment: If the ring is indeed commutative, assume that $a=2$ and $b=3$ and write the expansion explicitly. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using the binomial expansion: $(x+y)^{a+b}=\sum_{k=0}^{a+b}{a+b\choose k}x^ky^{a+b-k}$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: I have $x^{a+b} + {a+b \choose 1} x^{a+b-1} y^1 + \cdots + y^{a+b}$. And I think that: $x^{(a+b)}, x^{a+b-1} y^1,  y^{a+b} \in ideal $ but I don't know why? Because we only know that   $x^a \in I$ and $y^b \in I$. @AlekosRobotis

Comment: Well, if $k \le a$, then $a+b-k\ge b$...